# Handling multiple Series from a single Dataset

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, charts, dataset, series

I'm currently struggling to get my head around Charts in Visual Basic. I can import a single DataSet and assign it to a single Chart Series and that all works fine... However, I was wondering if it's possible to create multiple Series from a single DataSet. In a similar fashion as below:

```
Using con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Test\Response.mdb;")
    Dim MyQuery As String = "SELECT qry_Response_By_Date_1.Actual_Date, qry_Response_By_Date_1.Mood, Count(qry_Response_By_Date_1.Mood) AS CountOfMood FROM qry_Response_By_Date_1 GROUP BY qry_Response_By_Date_1.Actual_Date, qry_Response_By_Date_1.Mood HAVING (((qry_Response_By_Date_1.Mood)<>'No Response'));"
    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(MyQuery, con)
        Dim MyData As New OleDbDataAdapter(MyQuery, con)
        Dim MyDataSet As New DataSet
        con.Open()
        MyData.Fill(MyDataSet, "Table")
        ChrtMoodChanges.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables("Table")
        Dim Series1 As Series = ChrtMoodChanges.Series("Series1")
        Dim Series2 As Series = ChrtMoodChanges.Series("Series2")
        Dim Series3 As Series = ChrtMoodChanges.Series("Series3")
        Dim Series4 As Series = ChrtMoodChanges.Series("Series4")
        Series1.Name = "Happy"
        Series2.Name = "Neutral"
        Series3.Name = "Sad"
        Series4.Name = "Angry"
        ChrtMoodChanges.Series(Series1.Name).XValueMember = "Actual_Date WHERE Mood = 'Happy'"
        ChrtMoodChanges.Series(Series1.Name).YValueMembers = "CountOfMood WHERE Mood = 'Happy'"
        ChrtMoodChanges.Series(Series2.Name).XValueMember = "Actual_Date WHERE Mood = 'Neutral'"
        ChrtMoodChanges.Series(Series2.Name).YValueMembers = "CountOfMood WHERE Mood = 'Neutral'"
        ChrtMoodChanges.Series(Series3.Name).XValueMember = "Actual_Date WHERE Mood = 'Sad'"
        ChrtMoodChanges.Series(Series3.Name).YValueMembers = "CountOfMood WHERE Mood = 'Sad'"
        ChrtMoodChanges.Series(Series4.Name).XValueMember = "Actual_Date WHERE Mood = 'Angry'"
        ChrtMoodChanges.Series(Series4.Name).YValueMembers = "CountOfMood WHERE Mood = 'Angry'"
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

It's separating the data out that is the issue, so I was wondering if there was a real equivalent to my fictional *"WHERE Mood = 'Happy'"* codes.

Comment: `.Series(Series1.Name).XValueMember = "Actual_Date WHERE Mood = 'Happy'"` must be the column name in the datatable not the members of the series. So the Xvalue member column will be the same for all the the Yvaluemembers column name will vary

Comment: That's perfect!, Thank you. I was over complicating that. I added a PIVOT to the SQL query and that worked. Just changed CountOfMood of each to the Mood itself and PIVOT takes care of the rest.